# Multiple Chekck

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck with an issue/ on how to approach this problem.

In the attached image (sorry I am not allowed to add the image now and hence the link) you can see in the column R4 there is a number 20 (which is the week num). I want excel formula to search for this week num with the with the header in row 3. Now after matching it, so in this instance 20 which is availble in N3 (header with number 20) it must display the corresponding value which is 0 (N4). I used the following sumifs but I receive an error.

Formula: =SUMIFS(K4:P10929;K3:P3;R4;A4:A10929;V4)

The first condition is to search for the values and match the week num 20 with the row 3 and the second condition is to match the unique code for each row in the column v with the all the values from the column A.

I tried Index and Match too, but still facing an issue.

Formual: =INDEX(A4:P10929;MATCH(R4;A3:P3;0))

Any help on how to approach this problem would be much helpful.

Thanks

Image:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0xEN.png

Comment: A little confused by maybe `=INDEX(K4:P4,MATCH(R4,K$3:P$3,0))`

Comment: oh..thank you very much. This Formula works. I had been thinking in complex way and was blind that I made a mistake in my formula. Thanks again :)